# Git rebase when rebasing master with a feature - Understanding the rebase diagram

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

I just rebased master with my feature branch (which means that I merged master onto my feature branch). I used the following command on my feature branch:

```
git rebase -i master
```

I had the following four commits on my feature branch zzL1, zzL2, zzL3, zzL4. I squashed zzL1 and zzL2 into one commit message which was "This is a combined message of zzL1+zzL2". Here are the two questions that I have based on this:

1. When I rebased master on to my branch called zzf. It basically appears like master got merged on to my branch called zzf. However from what I understand is that rebasing being different from merge basically replays commit history. Does that mean it appears as if the commits that were on Master and missing on my branch will now appear as if they were also created on my branch ?
2. Can you explain this rebase diagram below?

   [image]

   The blue line is master and the red line is the feature branch. I am rebasing master onto my feature branch. Basically merging master onto my feature branch. Why are the rebase dots (with new commit msgs) showing up as dots on the master branch. Even though the changes of feature branch are not on the master branch.

Here is the code that i used

```
PS C:\Test\MsGitTest\proj> git rebase -i master
[detached HEAD 1aeb5a5] This is a combined meesage of zzL1+zzL2
 Date: Sun Sep 1 20:10:09 2019 -0700
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/zzF.
PS C:\Test\MsGitTest\proj> git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Here is the gitk diagram

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question. Voted +1. I would love to know the answer

Comment: There was more than just a rebase going on here. Looks like a rebase followed by a merge. Which makes no sense in any workflow I know of.

Comment: Nope only did rebase. I'll update my post

Comment: I only used the terminal. And then I pushed my changes up.

Comment: Is a branch checked out or are you in a `detached HEAD 1aeb5a5` state, as the message suggests? What does `git status` show in your situation?

Comment: No I was not in detached mode. After a rebase completed. I was back in my feature branch and i pushed my changes

Comment: Is there a difference between what your GUI is showing and what `git log` is showing? Also a note about the terminology, you are actually rebasing a feature branch onto master, not the other way around.

Comment: I just posted a picture of gitk as well

Comment: Everything is correct, `master` and `remote/master` are pointing to the same commit. you have 3 new commits on `zzF`

Answer (score 1):

> I am rebasing master onto my feature branch. Basically merging master
>   onto my feature branch.

This not true. This is what attlasian says about rebase:

> This moves the entire feature branch to begin on the tip of the master branch, effectively incorporating all of the new commits in master. **But, instead of using a merge commit, rebasing re-writes the project history by creating brand new commits for each commit in the original branch.**

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

So instead of "copy-ing" the commits from one branch to another (merge) you are making new commits and "copy-ing" the code and pushing these. Essentially CTRL+X + CTRL+V. You take branch A and just put it at the end of branch B.

The only weird thing is that your feature branch is "merging" back in to your main branch. This will not happen with a rebase. Maybe you rebased master on to your feature branch and then merged it back?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The short answer is Yes! Indeed, when you rebase onto master, your feature branch will have the newest changes from master. So for instance, you work on a feature branch, you have some commits on it. Then master has NEW commits, which are not in the feature branch. So to avoid merging master into feature, then feature into master, creating an ugly looking history, you can rebase your feature onto master, creating a cleaner looking history.
2. Although the graphs are confusing, they are showing that you have your `master` branch and `origin master` branch pointing to one commit. Then above that, you have 3 new commits that you creating when rebasing plus one merge commit from `zzF` branch.